# How to create an implementation for a interface through APIs automatically in java?

Tags: java

I am working with a certain spigot API called *net.minecraft.server.* in java. As such API basically changes the package ID every single version and basically not changing anything other than that, I would like to use reflection to call its methods.

However, reflections itself is repetitive to code and I would like to create some sort of a interface wrapper with the following example syntax :

```java
@BaseClass(name = String.format("org.bukkit.craftbukkit.%s.entity.CraftEntity", Application.getVersionID()))
public interface CraftEntityWrapper {
   @Field(name = "entity")
   EntityWrapper getEntity();

  
   @BaseClass(name = "some super class")
   void setPosition();

   @BaseClass(name = "some super class")
   @Field(name = "value")
   int getSomeValue();
}
```

I wish that the implementation could automatically cast the value to the varaible in the function return type, or create a new wrapper as a return value if the return type of the function has a valid @BaseClass annotation.

To create a CraftEntityWrapper, I hope the following could be done:

```java
public class WhateverImplementation {
   @Inject
   MyAPI instance;

   public void someMethod(){
      // Entity is a interface, and its implementation is CraftEntity 
      Entity entity; 

      CraftEntityWrapper wrapper= instance.createNewWrapper(CraftEntityWrapper.class, entity);
      wrapper.doSomething();
   }
}
```

Anyone know how to do that, I knew that MyBatis have done something similar but I don't know how to code such things from scratch, or maybe is there any existing API that does that?

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "As such API basically changes the package ID every single version".

Comment: basically something the content of the class is the same

but the API provided just changes the package ID name every version

something like
net.minecarft.server.V116.XXX and 
net.minecarft.server.V117.XXX

everything inside stays the same. The V116 I could get through reflection too.

Comment: So the api wants you to work with the interface, which hasn't the version in its package, why do you insist in the class?

Answer (score 0):

I am extremely curious why your spigot API changes its version at a package name level. It renders most code backward incompatible and leaves nightmares for the suport teams.

Still, restricting this response to your problem, it may not be possible as directly as you mention here. But you can have a basic set of text files which will contain tokens which will be replaced by your build process, before compilation. Essentially, you are generating sources out of these text files. What token to replace with what classname or constant can be sourced from a properties file or as properties within your build.

The processed text files will be your Java files which can then be compiled and your final project built.